# How to access Report FTP Folder in Automation Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio, ftp

I saved a Account Send Summary report from "Analytics Builder" > "Reports" to FTP using the option "FTP Result".

I can only choose the option "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP".

How I am supposed now to retrieve this report ?

I know that when I create a report from "Email Studio" > "Interactions" > "Reports", I am able to save an Account Summary Report to "ExactTarget Enhanced FTP" (thanks to the option "save in import folder (for reimport)" ) and then use it on the Automation Studio.

But it is impossible from there to make my report based on the Last 30 days (only the Past Month).

So is there a way to retrieve my Account Send Summary report with the last 30 days and automate this extract?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a FTP user (your MID) and password for your ExactTarget Enhanced FTP location.

Go to **Administration > Account > FTP Accounts**

[image]